# Singular vs. plural in the object of this sentence

Tags: singular-vs-plural, uncountable-nouns, countability, countable-nouns

These two sentences appear on the same page of an [online dictionary](http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-possessive-pronouns.html).

> Possessive pronouns are pronouns that demonstrate **ownerships**.
>
> Possessive pronouns include my, mine, our, ours, its, his, her, hers, their, theirs, your and yours - all words that demonstrate **ownership**.

It makes me wonder which form--plural or singular--makes more sense in this situation per se. I would go with plural. I am assuming the rational for the singular use is that the author takes ownership as an abstract concept here. But is this usage common enough to make sense/make the sentence sound natural?

Some more examples, as mentioned in a comment:

Oxford Online Dictionary:

> ‘Whenever press **ownerships** have been allowed into commercial television ownership, the situation has been favourable to the emergence of media moguls.’

Wikipedia pages (not Wiktionary):

> The company has evolved through several corporate **ownerships** since its establishment in 1960 in North Carolina.

Comment: I think the example sentence quoted from YD would read better with the singular _ownership_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with J.R. about the first example -- it looks strange as a plural.

The only time I'd use the plural *ownerships* is when the fact of multiple owners is exactly what's being discussed. This is the case in the Wikipedia example, and to a lesser extent in the Oxford -- it's important in those contexts to identify the fact that there are multiple owners, either in sequence or simultaneously.

Comment: Agreed, the online dictionary's "ownerships" could probably be considered a typo.